# Need to access a json response from a controller in laravel in my js

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, laravel

Please I need to access data from my laravel controller and display it with javascript in a page. How do you guys think I can go about this.

Below is my controller and  ajax call:

```js
var jq = jQuery.noConflict();
var id  = jq("#category_id").val();
jq.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {'X-CSRF-Token': jq("meta[name='_to

jq.ajax({
    url: '/netaviva/sportquiz/public/quiz/'+id+'/questions',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        if(data['success']){
            jq(data.records).each(function(i, item){
               console.log(item);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

```html
public function index($category_id)
{
    $questions = Question::where('category_id', '=',       $category_id)->orderBy(DB::raw('RAND()'))->take(3)->get()->toJson();
    return View::make('pages.questions',compact('questions', 'category_id'));
}
```

Route handling the controller request

```html
Route::match(['GET', 'POST'], '/{id}/questions', [
        'uses'=>'QuestionController@index',
        'as'=>'question'
    ]);
```

Comment: Is there a specific issue or problem you are facing or some kind of error you are getting?  Can you also show the route for `/netaviva/sportquiz/public/quiz/{id}/questions/`?

Comment: Where is the `{id}` in your ajax url set?

Comment: Sorry, made a mistake with the url,I have now changed the controller method to pass the id variable to the page and access it with jquery in my script  but I still can't access my json data. Thanks @Bhorn

Answer (score 0):

You need to access it like so data.success where data is your jquery function parameter and success is your array key